# GZIP compression / caching with NGINX

Tags: python-2.7, nginx

I've tried various methods of implementing GZIP on my nginx server, running a python/flask script. I'm trying to compress and cache static content, but nothing has worked so far.

my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file looks like this:

```
user nginx;
    worker_processes auto;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type        application/octet-stream;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        server {
            gzip              on;
            gzip_buffers      16 8k;
            gzip_comp_level   4;
            gzip_http_version 1.0;
            gzip_min_length   1280;
            gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp;
            gzip_vary         on;


            location ~*  \.(svg|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires 365d;
            }
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Dd you try putting it outside server block?

Comment: How did you see that the setting did not work?

Comment: I put the gzip options in under http and that seemed to work

Comment: not sure nginx cache content if gzip is used?